# "Filling" drum sound

Tags: sound-effects, vst, drum, echo, drumnbass

I'm looking for a technical description of how a particular drum sound can be made. Prodigy have it at 15th second in

for couple of seconds soloing.

I think those are made out of something resembling javanese taiko drum. I guess western tradition drums just do not have enough space in them to produce this 'filling' sound, the echo, rather than a kick itself.

This is all my non-professional thoughts. I'd love to hear a proof / another opinion. Also, just out of curiosity - is it possible to get a kick drum sound and somehow add this "echo" after it via effects? Any VST comes to mind?

Comment: when you say filling, I think you mean a drum fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sounds like it has another layer of big drum, taiko maybe, as you mentioned.

This can also be achieved through use of reverb that is sent through and envelope shaper/compressor or eq as you would need to keep only some transients

I would also use iZotope's alloy transient shaper - that's one vst that sprung in my mind

Comment: and some good ole pitch automation ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you'd be best finding a taiko-like sample. A kick drum with reverb most likely wont get you there. Toms and drums like these usually have a resonant aftertone that kicks dont have. If you wanted to synthesize something similar youd add a second smaller rise in amplitude after the initial hit combined with some kind of filter movement and pitch rise. How do you want to make this sound?

Comment: I ended up with using Taiko shots. Great stuff!